# Compare a list against a value to show that they are statistically different

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation

I have a list of values for a particular test and a single value from another test. How do I prove that the value for the single test is statistically significantly different or similar to the values on the list.

1) I got one suggestion that it is possible to generate a standard deviation measure for the list and then prove that the singular value is atleast two standard deviations away from my singular value of interest.

2) I got another suggestion to calculate the 5th percentile and 95th percentile of the list I have and then check to see if my value falls between the range.

I do all my stats on PRISM. I would be deeply obliged if somebody could suggest an easy way to do this comparison

Comment: "he said that t-tests are used to compare lists against lists and not for lists against a single value. " He is wrong, and would benefit from an introductory statistics course. The [one-sample *t* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) is ***precisely*** for comparing (the mean of) a list of values to a single value.

Comment: Suggestion 2, if applied to results of two identical tests, would tell you there is a "significant" difference 10% of the time.  Would you really trust the result of such a procedure?  Suggestion 1 is less predictable but in many circumstances would have even worse performance.

Comment: @whuber What do you suggest. Do I go with a one sample t-test.